# Other power series expansions about arbitrary points within the domain of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

According to the uniqueness of Taylor series about a point, if an infinitively-differentiable function $f(x)$ satisfies that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n(x-x_0)^n$, then we have $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}{(x_0)}}{n!}$;

Now we suppose that the series has a positive radius of convergence $R$，and the series converges within $(x_0-R,x_0+R)$;

My question is,

1. If we use the derivatives of another point $x_1$ different than $x_0$ within $(x_0-R,x_0+R)$ for the coefficients, that is , define $b_n=\frac{f^{(n)}{(x_1)}}{n!}$, does the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}b_n(x-x_0)^n$ always converge? If yes, is its radius of convergence $R_1$ somehow associated with $R$ ?(for example, $R_1=R-|x_1-x_0|$)
2. Does the power series expansion about $x_1$ $\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}b_n(x-x_1)^n\bigg)$ always have a positive radius of convergence $R_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proposition 1.2.3 of Krantz and Park's book *A Primer of Real Analytic Functions* (2nd edition) addresses this exact question. Using your notation, the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(x-x_1)^n$ is *at least* $R - |x_1 - x_0|$.

Intuitively, the radius of convergence of a convergent power series is the farthest distance you can extend the function in a disk. So it goes as far as it can until the boundary hits some singularity, regardless of where you center the series.

See also [Analytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) from Wikipedia.